# Expats etiquette

Tags: discussion, expat-questions

As a relatively new user of the site I'm puzzled.

Take [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109145/article-10-residence-card) as an example.

I looked at this and determined that it's a question about migration so I flagged it for migration and left a comment suggesting the OP repost. While I was doing this another member has posted an answer.

Now, the answer is fine, but it seems to me that by answering the question on Travel the incentive for the OP to repost on Expatriates is removed. This reduces the traffic to the Expatriates site, and blurs the distinction between the two sites.

There are comments elsewhere on this Meta about the beta status of Expatriates and the need to generate traffic there before it can graduate.

What is the policy here? Should I flag questions like this, or just ignore them. Is it appropriate to answer them here, or should those who answer be more encouraging to migration or repost?

Comment: When in doubt flag. Write us a complete and detailed message and we'll act accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the policy here? Should I flag questions like this, or just ignore them

Please flag them. But be aware that mods cannot respond to every flag instantly - it currently takes an average of 5 hours for us to process a given flag.

> Is it appropriate to answer them here, or should those who answer be more encouraging to migration or repost?

It's okay either way as answers are also migrated to Expats eventually, so no harm is done. If you feel like answering it straight away feel free to flag it and then post your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan. I don't expect an instant response from the moderators. I just wanted some clarification on the right process.

Comment: The question in question was not entirely about immigration; it also included the paragraph "Can I not go England with my wife using my EU residence card (which i acquired through work contract, and living in Greece), and marriage certificate? Can I not even visit the UK like that?" which is on topic for TSE.

Answer (score 0):

I am the user who answered the question in question.  I did so because it included questions that are on topic at TSE:

> Can I not go England with my wife using my EU residence card (which i acquired through work contract, and living in Greece), and marriage certificate? Can I not even visit the UK like that?